# How to require dependencies in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, clojure-testing

I have two questions regarding dependencies in `Clojure` project.

1. Is there something like `:dev-dependencies` or `:test-dependencies` so that I don't have to download them all on `lein run`? So until I run my tests I don't need to have these extra libraries.
2. Can I load dependencies in one file and require this one file in an another file? I'd like to have something similar to:

   ```
   ; dependencies.clj
   ; ...

   (:require [clj-http.client :as client]
     [clj-http.fake   :refer :all]
     [clojure.test   :refer :all]))


   ; some-file.clj
   ; ...

   (:require [dependencies :refer :all[)
   ```

Comment: You might be able to use `load-file` for #2; I haven't tried it using it in this way.  This is a non-standard strategy, and I think people would tell you not to do it, but if it works, I'm not sure why it would actually be bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Yes, Leiningen offers [profiles](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/PROFILES.md) for just these [purposes](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj#L160)

2) No, referals from one namespace  are not "inherited" between namespaces. You can't express "I want to refer to everything in this namespace, that some other namespace refers"

Comment: Here is the explanation: http://blog.8thlight.com/kevin-buchanan/2014/12/08/organizing-your-clojure-environment-and-logs-with-leiningen.html

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your point 2, [Potemkin](https://github.com/ztellman/potemkin) can help you do this. Potemkin is especially useful if you have several namespaces implementing the functionality of a library, but then want to present a single namespace to users of the library.